# Can't use FormData in UI material forms to fetch form field values

Tags: django, reactjs, fetch

I am just trying to post data from my UI-material form into backend.

I am using react hooks here.

Below is code that i am trying to do using simple fetch.

```
  const [name, setName] = useState ('');
  const [email_id, setEmail] = useState ('');
  const [subject, setSubject] = useState ('');

  const onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const data = new FormData(e.target);
    console.log(data);
    fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/contact/", {
      method: "POST",
      body: data,
    })
      .catch((error) => console.log("Request failed", error));
  }
```

This is the material UI form which i am using

```
<form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
            <TextField
              autoComplete="new-password"
              id="outlined-basic"
              label="Full Name"
              variant="outlined"
              value={name}
              onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
              required
            />
            <TextField
              id="outlined-basic"
              label="Email Address"
              variant="outlined"
              autoComplete="new-password"
              value={email_id}
              onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
              required
            />
            <TextareaAutosize
              className="textbox"
              aria-label="minimum height"
              rowsMin={3}
              placeholder="Subject"
              value={subject}
              onChange={(e) => setSubject(e.target.value)}
            />
            <button>Submit</button>
          </form>
```

While using with material UI form it gives me error that says

```
{"name":["This field is required."],"email_id":["This field is required."],"subject":["This field is required."]}
```

When i use normal html form it works perfectly fine. But when i try to do the same with material-UI form it doesnt work.

It will be really helpful if anyone can help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set a name attribute to the input fields so they get submitted with the form.

In material-ui you can set name prop of the `TextField` and any other input field, for example:

```
<TextField
  autoComplete="new-password"
  id="outlined-basic"
  name="name"
  label="Full Name"
  variant="outlined"
  value={name}
  onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
  required
/>
```